# Boxplot and split in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called Insectsprays that has two columns, count and spray.  When I try to use split to create boxplots for each value of spray, I get the error shown below.

Can anyone explain the error for me? It's no doubt clear I'm new to R.

```
#
class(InsectSprays)
[1] "data.frame"

#
head(InsectSprays)  
  count spray   
1    10     A   
2     7     A   
3    20     A   
4    14     A   
5    14     A   
6    12     A   

#
boxplot(split(x=InsectSprays,f=InsectSprays$spray))  
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) :   
  'x' must be atomic
```

Comment: `split(x=InsectSprays,f=InsectSprays$spray)` gives you a list of data frames. you need a list of vectors for boxplot: `boxplot(split(x=InsectSprays$count,f=InsectSprays$spray))`

Answer (score 2):

`boxplot` expects a basic ('atomic') object like a series of numbers `1:10` or a `list` of basic atomic objects `list(1:10,2:11)`. Your `split` produces a `list` of `data.frames` which `boxplot` doesn't know how to handle. Luckily, `boxplot` can also take a formula if you want to get results per group, like:

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data=InsectSprays)
```

If you were working with a different function that didn't have this possibility, you would need to loop over the `split` `list`. Possibly something like:

```
## divide the plot window into 3 columns/2 rows
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
## loop over each object and `boxplot` the `count` column
lapply(split(InsectSprays, InsectSprays$spray), \(x) boxplot(x$count) )
```